# Why does DRF receive my jquery ajax request as arrays?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django-rest-framework

I have the following problem:
I call $.ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/endpoint',
  headers: {"X-CSRFToken": csrf_token},
  data: { 
    'action': 'my-action', 
    'data': {'text': 'blah'}
});
```

and on the Django Rest Framework I get weirdly

```
request.data == {'action': ['my-action'], 'data[text]':['blah']}
```

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was:

1.) jQuery sent the request with the wrong encoding, needed to add

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/endpoint',
  headers: {"X-CSRFToken": csrf_token},
  contentType: 'application/json',  // <-- this
  data: { 
    'action': 'my-action', 
    'data': {'text': 'blah'}
});
```

2.) DRF parses www form encoding by default, so in the viewset I needed to add

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    parser_classes = [JSONParser]
```

and this got me

```
request.data == {'action': 'my-action', 'data': {'text': 'blah'}}
```

that I was looking for.